# unable to install torch_sparse package

Tags: python

```
'''
pip install torch_sparse
Collecting torch_sparse
  Using cached torch_sparse-0.6.12.tar.gz (43 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /home/tanojlangore/anaconda3/envs/my-rdkit-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from torch_sparse) (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.23.0,>=1.16.5 in /home/tanojlangore/anaconda3/envs/my-rdkit-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scipy->torch_sparse) (1.21.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: torch-sparse
  Building wheel for torch-sparse (setup.py) ... [?25l-
```

'''

it keeps on running for infinite time...

Answer (score 2):

As per the official documentation https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html, if you are using PyTorch version <=1.9.* you need to specify the version number of the package you are installing like this:

```
pip3 install torch-sparse==0.6.12 --no-cache-dir -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.9.0+cu111.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [this web tool](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/installation.html) to found the working version for your situation.
For example if I select pytorch1.10.* + Linux + pip + CPU I obtain:

```
pip install torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-cluster torch-spline-conv torch-geometric -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cpu.html
```

And I can maintain only torch-sparse:

```
pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cpu.html
```

If you have a version of pytorch < 1.9.* you will have problems maybe.

Answer (score 0):

How long have you been waiting? I also thought that I have a problem but after 15-20 minutes it suddenly finished